# Test the convergence of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Test the convergence of the following integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}.$$I can not find the indefinite integral of the integrand so that we can check at the limits $-\infty$ and $\infty$ Also I can not apply any theorem about convergence , like Ables test, Dirichlet's test...etc... Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is divergent, the integrand doesn't converge to $0$ as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: this integral doesn't exist.

Comment: @Solitary That is not necessary! There are examples of functions where the integrand doesn't converge to $0$ but they are still integrable! For example, consider shrinking triangles. What you mean is that it diverges to $\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should add that the integrand is nonnegative as well.

Comment: @Solitary The integrand can be nonnegative and still not converge to $0$

Comment: @avid19 Really? Can you provide an explicit example?

Comment: @Solitary As I had said, shrinking triangles/bumps, so long as they decay in a way. For example if you have triangles with area $\frac{1}{2^n}$, then the integral would just be $2$ even though the limit doesn't exist. What we CAN say though, is that IF the limit exists, THEN it must be $0$. However the limit doesn't have to exist. For an even more trivial example. consider the $0$ function that is modified so $f(n)=1$ for $n\in \Bbb{Z}$. This limit doesn't exist, but the integral is $0$.

Comment: Oh, what I really meant is if the integral converges (let's say nonnegative integrand), then the integrand must converge to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ **almost everywhere**, I believe that is true, right?

Comment: @Solitary I'm not quite sure I know what $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = L a.e.$ would mean rigorously. Either way the shrinking bumps would not be a.e. in any sense of the word.

Comment: The integrand is positive and $\to \infty$ as $x\to -\infty.$ Therefore the integral diverges.

Comment: @avid, Solitary) Please explain how it is convergent or divergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow @Solitary comment. Let $f(x)$ be the integrand function.
Notice that
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty
$$
hence there is some $b<0$ such that for all $x<b$ one has $f(x)>1$ hence for all $a<b$ one has
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ge b-a \to +\infty
$$
as $a\to -\infty$.

Hence
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) = +\infty.
$$
This assumes that you are speaking of *improper integrals*. If you are speaking of Lebesgue integrals the solution is even simpler...